# DrawerLayout + SurfaceView + TouchListener

Tags: android, touch, surfaceview, drawerlayout, drawer

I want to use a DrawerLayout together with a SurfaceView (MetaioSDK Augmented Reality View). Everything is working fine except the TouchListener for the SurfaceView. 
It looks like that the FrameLayout inside the DrawerlLayout blocks my Touch-Events for the SurfaceView. Is it possible to delegate the Event directly to the SurfaceView? I would appreciate some help from some pros.

Below is my xml-layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tV_Attributes"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hier sollen Attribute angezeigt werden." />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend the FrameLayout to ignore touch events, if it was landed on SurfaceView.

In your FrameLayout:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (isHitToView(ev, view)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}

public static boolean isHitToView(MotionEvent event, View view) {
    if (view == null || event == null || view.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
        return false;

    Rect r = new Rect();
    //r.left и r.top - всегда нули
    view.getLocalVisibleRect(r);

    int[] coordinates = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(coordinates);

    r.left += coordinates[0];
    r.right += coordinates[0];
    r.top += coordinates[1];
    r.bottom += coordinates[1];

    float x = event.getRawX();
    float y = event.getRawY();

    if (r.right >= x && r.top <= y && r.left <= x && r.bottom >= y)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My solution is the following inspired by your answer.

public class CustomDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {
   ...
    @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
     super.onTouchEvent(ev);
  if(ev.getX() > 30 && ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
   Log.d("CustomDrawerLayout", "onTouchEvent: false");
   return false;
  }else{
   Log.d("CustomDrawerLayout", "onTouchEvent: true");
   return true;
  }
 }
}